# Expressing "more importantly" in a subtle way

Tags: phrase-usage

I am expressing the following:

> I did X, Y, and Z. More importantly, I also learned to do *this*.

For context, X, Y, and Z, are technical skills while *this* is a "soft" skill. When saying "more importantly" I don't want to downplay "X, Y, and Z," but I want to stress that I learned the more difficult (and possibly more valuable) "soft" skill.

By simply stating "I did X, Y, and Z. I also learned to do *this*," I feel as though the 2nd statement is not getting enough importance.

Am I just overthinking my statements or is there a way to express significance without downplaying the other?

Comment: If "*this*" is a more difficult (and possibly more valuable) "soft" skill then "**more important**" fits in perfectly. You should revise your personal thought on this matter.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment you can use "**besides that**" which can seem a little less important, or "**among other things**", or even "**in addition to that**". There's also "**as well**" which you should place at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "at the same time" -

> I did X, Y, and Z, but at the same time, I also learned to do *this*.

This shows that while you were working on X, Y and Z, you also gave equal importance to learning "this".